# Adding text input to image

Tags: html, jquery

I have 3 different text inputs that I would like to place over an image after the user types in the text. I have some knowledge of HTML/CSS/jQuery, but have no idea where to start.

Each text input should be on it's own line in the color white over top of this plaque:

[Plaque image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnHfK.jpg)

**Line1**: Sample Text
**Line2**: Sample Text
**Line3**: Sample Text

Comment: At least show us what you've tried: this should be easily achieved by using your image as a background-image with sufficient padding in the element, so the lines are not flush against the edges.

Comment: Welcome to SO, since this isn't a code writing service I would check out [mcve]. When it comes to what you need to learn to do what you are trying, you really need: Setting an image as the background of a div, absolutely positioning divs (for the text elements), input event handler and using `innerHTML` to place the input

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your text inputs in a `<div>` and set the Plague image as the background for the `<div>` using CSS.

```css
    #plague_text{
      background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH5zB.jpg")
    }
    
    #line1, #line2, #line3{
      background: transparent;
    }
```

```html
    <div id = "plague_text">
      <label for="line1">Line1:</label>
      <input type="text" id="line1" name="line1"></br>
      <label for="line2">Line2:</label>
      <input type="text" id="line2" name="line2"></br>
      <label for="line3">Line3:</label>
      <input type="text" id="line3" name="line3"></br>
    </div>
```

[Read more about CSS background-image Property here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Comment: Thanks for providing a helpful answer unlike others!